# visual c++ dataGridView cellclick event

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, datagridview, c++-cli, clr

I googled about `cellclick` event in `dataGridView` for `c++`. All results are about `c#`.
My `dataGridView1` selection mode is `FullRowSelect`. My target is when I clicked to any cell (row), detect that row and do something.

```
int i;
private: System::Void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellEventArgs^  e)
{
   if (double clicked row 1)
   { 
      int = 1;
   }
   if (double clicked row 2)
   {
      int = 2;
   }
}
```

I need any simple example or any source for learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ok found a solution on c# tutorials and converted for c++-clr

```
    if (e->RowIndex == 1) //that's what i looking for, you can use ColumnIndex too.
{
    int = 1;
}
```

works perfect for c++-clr.

DataGridViewCell.RowIndex Property on msdn helps too.